# which heatmap library/software can be used on ajax rich site ?

Tags: ajax, analytics, heatmap

I am developing an ajax heavy site, where almost all of the content is loaded dynamically. The technique does have its benefits - enhanced UX, caching. However, I can not find an open source heat map (to chart clicks) solution  that fits such site ?

These days, lots of sites are being made ajax-rich or hijax based - just wondering what options do they use for analytics - more specifically heatmaps.

Comment: No replies ? Haven't described properly or does nobody use heatmaps ?